# I don't know why my request upload is returning a 422 error if the path is correct

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, upload

I want to upload a file to a movie in a database, but each time I pass a file type, it will return a 422 error, without any details of what could cause the bug.

Here is my code of upload in simplified:

```
            <label for="fImageMovie">Sélectionner l'image de l'affiche du film:</label>
            <input id="image-upload" type="file" @change="onImageChange">
            <span :class="{ 'error': !isPosterValid }">{{ textErrorPoster }}</span>
```

Here I change my size of file to make it acceptable and notice the user

```
        onImageChange(event) {
            const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);

            reader.onload = () => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;
                img.onload = () => {
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    const maxWidth = 600;
                    const maxHeight = 600;
                    let width = img.width;
                    let height = img.height;

                    if (width > maxWidth) {
                        height *= maxWidth / width;
                        width = maxWidth;
                    }
                    if (height > maxHeight) {
                        width *= maxHeight / height;
                        height = maxHeight;
                    }

                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                        const resizedFile = new File([blob], selectedFile.name, { type: selectedFile.type });
                        this.posterImage = resizedFile;
                    }, selectedFile.type);
                };
            };
        },
```

My code for upload is :

```
        async addPosterToMovie(idMovie) {
            const userStore = useUsersStore()
            const responseStatus = await uploadImage(idMovie, this.posterImage, userStore.userToken);
            if (responseStatus) {
                this.isAddingPosterToMovieCorrect = true;
                this.responseTextPoster = "Le poster a été ajouté correctement au film avec succès!";
            } else {
                this.isAddingPosterToMovieCorrect = false;
                this.responseTextPoster = "Cependant une erreur s'est produite lors de l'ajout du film au poster.";
            }

        }
```

It is important to notice that my link for upload is

```
https://laravel-e23.herokuapp.com/api/{id_films}/upload
```

```
let baseURL = 'https://laravel-e23.herokuapp.com/api/'
let headers = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
};
```

const FILMS_SELECTOR = "films";

const UPLOAD_KEYWORD = "/upload";

Upload real code:

```
export async function uploadImage(idMovieToAddPoster, image, token) {

    const headersWithToken = {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
    };
    
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', image)
    
    const response = await fetch(baseURL + FILMS_SELECTOR + "/" + idMovieToAddPoster + UPLOAD_KEYWORD, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headersWithToken,
        body: formData
    });
    return response.status == 200
}
```

If you want to try it on postman
Try first to have login token and pass it with:
https://laravel-e23.herokuapp.com/api/login
With :

```
{
    "email": "karine@email.com",
    "password": "password"
}
```

But the admin user has changed from now but soon, it will regoto these values

I try adding form data in the method, but there is still error 422, even without it. I resize the image, because, It is necessary if it is too much space for it. Just to be just, but every parameter in api, is not null, and file is defined with values in it.

Comment: did you see the yellow warning popup when you used the VS Code tag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user I only used console on chrome, and the code is returning a file ( File {name: '71IjkDc8w-L._AC_SY879_.jpg', lastModified: 1683897199155, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 12 2023 09:13:19 GMT-0400 (heure d’été de l’Est nord-américain), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 63866, …}) Which should have been correct but it is not the case